# CSS border Issue : failing to render left border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a border on the left side, but it doesn't show after the first div(breadCrumb). The HTML code is following :-

```
<div class="contentHolder">
    <div class="breadCrumb">
        <a href="http://www.pricetag.com">Store </a>>>&nbsp;Electronics 
    </div>
    <div class="contentMainDiv">
        <div class="leftDiv"><p>orem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code is following :

> .contentHolder { padding: 10px 0 0 10px; border-left: 1px solid #CCC; }
>
> .contentHolder div.breadCrumb { font-size:12px; }
>
> .contentHolder div.breadCrumb a {color:#408080; text-decoration:none; }
>
> .contentHolder div.breadCrumb a:hover {text-decoration:underline; }
>
> .contentHolder div.leftDiv{ float:left; width: 150px; }
>
> .contentHolder div.rightDiv { float:left;}

**Below is Image for the Error Page** : -

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [clear/contain the floated elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) in `.contentMainDiv`.

One way to do that is to add `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: I am bit unknown to CSS technicalities. Can you please edit your answer and tell how and when should i use clear. My project has many floating elements so i need to know when to use it and how to use it. Thanks

Comment: You just have to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent of elements with `float` set to `left` or `right`: http://jsfiddle.net/AavNv/

Comment: Ya, i understood that. So, is this enough for all problems and i dont need to worry about clearfix and `clear:both` property ?. I read them somewhere in regard to float so asking about them.

Comment: Clearfix is a different way to clear floats. That works in the same way - instead of applying `overflow: hidden` to the parent of floated elements, you apply `class="clearfix"`. `overflow: hidden` works in almost all cases and is simpler. `clear: both` can do the same thing, but it involves adding an extra `<div>` every time you want to clear floats, so don't do that. The only real use for `clear: both` is for instances when you already have the element there, such as the footer beneath two floated columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
.contentHolder div.leftDiv{ float:left; width: 150px; }
```

remove float: left or use clearfix http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/ for contentHolder class

preview http://jsfiddle.net/TrePF/

```css
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
.clearfix { display: inline-table; }
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* End hide from IE-mac */
.contentHolder { padding: 10px 0 0 10px; border-left: 1px solid #CCC; }

.contentHolder div.breadCrumb { font-size:12px; }

.contentHolder div.breadCrumb a {color:#408080; text-decoration:none; }

.contentHolder div.breadCrumb a:hover {text-decoration:underline; }

.contentHolder div.leftDiv{ float:left; width: 150px; }

.contentHolder div.rightDiv { float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="contentHolder clearfix">
    <div class="breadCrumb">
        <a href="http://www.pricetag.com">Store </a>>>&nbsp;Electronics 
    </div>
    <div class="contentMainDiv">
        <div class="leftDiv"><p>orem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` to `.contentHolder`

```
.contentHolder {
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  float: left;
}
```

Either should work.